# Tell me what it means blockinfo?

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core

If you can please me more.

bitcoin/src/test/**miner_tests.cpp**

Here is an example code.

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/test/miner_tests.cpp#L43-L72

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a variable name.

It holds the nonces needed to build a test blockchain.

Comment: And how they can be received?

Comment: There is nothing to receive. It is data for the construction of dummy blocks with no meaning.